# Table Not Displaying as 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I've been having a few problems aligning tables on Twitter bootstrap. I've been trying to avoid fixed widths etc. I seem to have table 100% and even title 78% to fill up the space when the titles aren't so long.

You can see my main table problem here: 
[MY TABLE THAT WONT ALIGN CENTER](http://www.onlinebanter.com/football-betting)

Its the middle table below the livescore. The div class view-taxonomy-term. I was wanting it to fill up the whole of that middle space 'region-content'.

I've been at it for hours; text-aligning center, margin 0px etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the table only has a `max-width:100%;` property, which only *limits* the maximum width of the table. If you want to *set* the width of the table, you should use the `width` property. For example:

```
.views_table {
     ...
     width:100%;
     ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want the table to be centered, you can try setting the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties to `auto`:

```
.views_table {
    ...
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* or in shorthand - margin:0 auto;*/
    ...
}
```

Comment: ah thanks Boaz. Truth be told i accidently left that in. Ive been trying everything. Let me go change it and see.....ah brilliant that seems to have sorted (till i realise why i changed it from 100% width)